# Javascript: Calling method of each object in array without iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

Is there an elegant way of calling a method on each object in an array without iteration?

Edit: The intent of the question was to ask "without a for loop, or without any iteration if possible" Sorry for the confusion

```
var dogs = [new Dog("Max"), new Dog("Buddy"), new Dog("Charlie")];

for(var i=0; i<dogs.length; i++){
    dogs[i].sayName();
}

function Dog(name){

    this.name = name;

    this.sayName = function(){
         console.log(this.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: `dogs.forEach(dog => dog.sayName());`?

Comment: To everyone answering this question: isn't `forEach()` a form of iteration?

Comment: Sure, it is a form of iteration.

Comment: Is the intent to ask "without a for loop?"

Comment: Do you consider recursion to be iteration?

Answer (score 4):

## No

Doing something on each array item means you iterate the array.

So it's not possible to do it without iterating the array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
dogs.forEach(function(elem) {
   console.log(elem.sayName());
}
```

Alternatively you can use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which returns a new array

```
dogs.map(function(elem) {
   return elem.name;
}
```

If you are using array.map() you should return something so you don't end up with a new array of undefined values, if you intend on using the returned array.

Using forEach() seems like a better fit in your use case.

However as @Barmar points out, both methods still iterate over each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Even the object initialisation could be done in a similar way with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var dogs = ['Max','Buddy','Charly'].map(name => new Dog(name));
dogs.forEach(dog => dog.sayName());

function Dog(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.sayName = function(){
         console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
dogs.map(function(thisDog) { thisDog.sayName(); })
```

The callback for `map` takes three arguments: the current value, the current index, and the array. But in your case you only need the current value so you don't need to provide the other two arguments.

Comment: *map* also creates a new Array from the return values of the callback function, which is a bit wasteful as it's not needed. *forEach* is a better option as it doesn't do that. I wish down voters would spend some time explaining their vote.